# Is it worth swapping Ctrl and Caps Lock for windows users that don't use Emacs

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, touch-typing

I've been aware of Steve Yegge's advice to [swap Ctrl and Caps Lock](http://steve.yegge.googlepages.com/effective-emacs#item1) for a while now, although I don't use Emacs. I've just tried swapping them over as an experiment and I'm finding it difficult to adjust. There are several shortcuts that are second nature to me now and I hadn't realised quite how ingrained they are in how I use the keyboard.

In particular, I keep going to the old Ctrl key for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (undo), and for cut, copy & paste operations (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>V</kbd>). Experimenting with going from the home position to  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> I don't know which finger to put on <kbd>Z</kbd>, as it feels awkward with either my ring, middle or index finger. Is this something I'll get used to the same way I've got used to the original position and I should just give it time or **is this arrangement not suited to windows keyboard shortcuts**.

I'd be interested to hear from people who have successfully made the transition as well as those who have tried it and move back, but particularly from people who were doing it on **windows**.

Will it lead to any improvement in my typing speed or comfort when typing.

Do you have any tips for finger positions or typing training to speed up the transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up taking the advice in Zach's answer, but I also made <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> behave as an <kbd>ESC</kbd> key if it was held and released on it's own using the AutoHotKey script in this gist: [CapsLockCtrlEscape.ahk](https://gist.github.com/sedm0784/4443120)

I also bound <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> for the rare occasions when I might need it using this AutoHotKey script:

```
#IfWinActive
   ^+Capslock::Capslock ; make CTRL+SHIFT+Caps-Lock the Caps Lock toggle
return
```

Answer (score 29):

I actually don't swap control and caps and just make caps ANOTHER control key.  I can't think of a single time in my life when I have ever hit caps-lock on **purpose**, so I haven't missed it.

That way, you get used to using it, but if you slip up and use the old control, things still work.  It's worked out very well for me.

There's a .reg file to do this [here](http://johnhaller.com/jh/useful_stuff/disable_caps_lock/caps_lock_to_control.reg).

Comment: Is there a way to do this inside of emacs--say, if I don't have admin access to a Windows machine so I can't modify the registry?

Comment: +1 for making it another caps lock key. @onebyone.livejournal.com: If you don't need alt-gr, I guess that you have never used any international keyboard layout?

Comment: Without it, I need to press Ctrl+Alt to input any of the following: @ (important),£ (not very useful), § (what the hell is this?), {[]} (essential), ¨ (not in my language).

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to find, but I foolishly searched for regedit instead of reg - I created exactly that reg file and it works great!

Comment: I want to swap capslock with RIGHT control, couldn't goole it, has anybody got such .reg file? (there is only with-left-control-swap in the link) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've done it for quite a while now, and it's natural to me, even though I'm not an Emacs user either (I'm in the Vim camp of that particular war :) ). In fact, it's so natural that moving to other machines (coworkers, family members, etc.) causes me grief because Ctrl isn't where it 'ought' to be.

Comment: I'm in the Emacs camp, but I've got the impression that Vim gurus change their caps lock key to esc? :)

Comment: For Vim users switching caps lock and control is still favorable because ctrl+[ is the same as escape.  Thus you can have the control placed conveniently for other applications and avoid the extra few inch stretch to the escape key.

Answer (score 2):

For emacs ctrl should be at caps lock - for vim the escape key should be on the caps lock.  I really feel that the caps lock button should be renamed "free parking" and OSes should make a system tray utility to quickly change the free parking button from escape, to control, to anything you need to type over and over again.

Comment: If it weren't a Windows system, I'd agree. For me, the regular use of Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V, Ctrl-A, Ctrl-X, etc. in Windows makes it more useful to swap Caps Lock with Ctrl on Windows systems,even though I'm a vim user.

Comment: Caps lock is quite simple to rebind in OS X and Gnome at least. Only Windows seems to make it complex (and maybe some Linux window managers I guess)

Answer (score 1):

I switched the Caps Lock and Ctrl keys a couple of months ago and after the initial learning period, ~ 1 week, my biggest problem is when I use a computer that hasn't switched the keys.

I first did some registry hack but I can't remember where I found the information on how to do it. Now I'm using a small utility called Remapkey which is included in the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools even though I think I'm using an older version.

Answer (score 0):

I had no problem making the transition.  I use keyboards with both configurations without issue.  Perhaps having it as a hardware solution (and the labels properly printed) makes it easier than doing it through software and having to remember how each machine/keyboard is setup.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's best to put on caps depends on your physical keyboard.

At home I type on a Kinesis Ergo Elan where my ctrl keys are under my thumbs, along with 2*alt, space, enter, backspace, delete, pgup, pgdn, home and end; the rest of the keyboard is fairly normally laid out, except the board is split.

With the ctrl keys ready at hand, it really makes the most sense to put escape on caps lock (and caps lock on esc, for the few times I need it).  Even if you're an emacser, hey... it doubles as a spare "prefix alt key", and you probably ask your browser to stop what it's doing a few times every day.

On the other hand, if I'm typing on my laptop where the lower left corner key is Fn rather than ctrl (ffs...) and I can't hold down shift+ctrl with one finger, it might make sense to put ctrl on caps (such that I can hold them with a single finger).  At least if you're not a vi'er, or you don't mind the escape key being further away (or have some crazy system).

What's really interesting is putting some funky key on shift+shift (yep, both shift keys).  This can be done with xmodmap fairly straightforwardly; I put my compose key there.  If you don't need compose, you may want to put something else (like, say, esc).

Answer (score 0):

Copy the following code into a file called caps-ctrl-swap.reg, execute the file, agree to allow registry to be changed, log out and back in and your caps-lock and left-ctrl keys will be swapped. I've used this script for whatever version of Windows was current in 2005 and every version in between. I needed it today since Windows 10 updated overnight and it still works great.

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,1d,00,3a,00,3a,00,1d,00,00,00,00,00
```