# How to globally map AltGr key to Alt key?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I want my <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key to behave exactly like left <kbd>Alt</kbd>.
Usually, I do this kind of stuff with [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), but I'm open to different solutions.

I tried this:

```
LControl & RAlt::Alt
```

And Autohotkey displayed error about `Alt` not being recognized action.
Then I tried the following code:

```
LControl & RAlt::
  Send {Alt down}
  KeyWait LCtrl
  KeyWait Ralt
  Send {Alt up}
return
```

which sort of works - I'm able to use the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key for accessing hotkeys, but it still behaves differently:
When I press and release the left <kbd>Alt</kbd>, the first menu item in the current program receives focus.
Pressing and releasing <kbd>AltGr</kbd> with this script does nothing.

Any ideas? Is this even possible with Autohotkey? (remapping right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> to their left siblings was piece of cake)

---

Note: I tried switching `Alt` to `LAlt` in the code and it made no difference.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Thank you all for answers. I was unable to solve this using AutoHotkey -- PhilLho's answer was close, but I really needed exatly the same behaviour as with left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

However, the [registry thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229633/how-to-globally-map-altgr-key-to-alt-key#396859) actually worked as I needed.

Save this as *AltGR_to_LeftAlt.reg* file and run it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,38,00,38,e0,00,00,00,00
```

Or, there is a GUI tool that does this for you -- it's called [SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys) and works peachy:
[image: SharpKeys in action]

Oh, and don't forget to reboot or log off -- it won't work until then!

Comment: This answer is wrong: SharpKeys does not support Alt Gr. (https://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/workitem/10375)

Comment: `Right Alt` worked as a substitute for `AltGr` for my purposes (remapping bootcamp `Cmd` to `AltGr`), with the one difference that I had to select it manually from the list. "The right Alt key is usually an equivalent of the AltGr key" - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key

Comment: This answer is correct. I have successfully remapped my left and right ALT keys on my mac keyboard with SharpKeys. You need two mappings, one for `left<=>right` and `right<=>left` swapping of ALT keys.

Comment: How do you undo this please?

Answer (score 8):

As pointed out by PhiLho, Windows provides a way to remap any key, through the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout`.  A basic overview can be found at [Scan Code Mapper for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/archive/w2kscan-map.mspx).  A better description is probably [Answers to Scancode Mapping or Changing Key Values](https://web.archive.org/web/20120323030858/www.annoyances.org/exec/forum/win2000/n1019911460).

I'm using this approach to put the `Windows Key` on the `Caps Lock`, because my keyboard doesn't have a `Windows Key` and I don't need the `Caps Lock`.

Comment: Since I'm not supposed to add software to my work machine, this is really useful.  I used the Scan Code Mapper for Windows link to map Caps to Ctrl before stumbling across the ready-made reg file at ["Is it worth swapping Ctrl and Caps..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127973/is-it-worth-swapping-ctrl-and-caps-lock-for-windows-users-that-dont-use-emacs).

Answer (score 4):

I got a decent behavior by combining two hotkeys:

```
LControl & RAlt::Send {Alt}
RAlt::Alt
```

The first one is for the standalone keypress (avoid to hold it down...), the second one to be used as combination (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, etc.).
It isn't perfect, you can't do a combination like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, but perhaps it is enough for your needs.

Note that you can do a permanent remapping using the registry. See [this forum post](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=9150) for an example. Not sure that it applies to compound keys like this one, but I thought I should mention it...

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
LControl & *RAlt::Send {LAlt Down}
LControl & *RAlt Up::Send {LAlt Up}
```

And this for mapping it to the Windows key:

```
LControl & *RAlt::Send {LWin Down}
LControl & *RAlt Up::Send {LWin Up}
```

Registry modification using SharpKeys (see above) is more reliable though (if you have administrator access).

Comment: Why do you map combination of `LControl` and `RAlt` instead of `RAlt` alone?

Comment: When you press AltGr Windows actually signals that you pressed both right Alt and left Ctrl keys.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,38,00,38,e0,00,00,00,00
```

1. Save the above code in reg file.
2. Merge it in registry.
3. Restart your PC.
4. Now check.

Answer (score 0):

In AHK, Can you do:

```
LControl & RAlt::!
```

Or

```
<^>!::!
```

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work for me.  
The first examples returns the "not recognized action" error and the second one does nothing at all.  
Of course, it is possible that something is wrong with my setup. Did it work on your side?

Comment: I don't have the key, but looking in the AHK documentation showed this that the <^>! is the symbol for AltGr.
Right Click TrayIcon-->Help-->Hotkeys

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map this key globally and with no need to restart system for every change (but once), you may need to write a keyboard filter driver for this purpose. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12612355/swap-alt-keys-functionality).